# PHP Извлечь hash из magnet-ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть magnet-ссылка
`$url = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e83dff8134c833a3c18f5c394eae55e3be854d94&dn=rutor.info_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80+%2F+Lucifer+%5B02x01-07+%D0%B8%D0%B7+22%5D+%282016%29+WEB-DLRip+%7C+Jaskier&tr=udp://opentor.org:2710&tr=udp://opentor.org:2710&tr=http://retracker.local/announce";`
Нужно получить с помощью регулярки это значение, как пример: **e83dff8134c833a3c18f5c394eae55e3be854d94**
Подскажите добрые люди, а то я в регулярках ни бум-бум!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e83dff8134c833a3c18f5c394eae55e3be854d94&dn=rutor.info_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80+%2F+Lucifer+%5B02x01-07+%D0%B8%D0%B7+22%5D+%282016%29+WEB-DLRip+%7C+Jaskier&tr=udp://opentor.org:2710&tr=udp://opentor.org:2710&tr=http://retracker.local/announce";

preg_match("#urn:btih:(.*?)\&dn#",$url,$out);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($out);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант для PHP (magnet:)?(xt=urn)?(.*)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]